# How do I get multiple records with no join table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have 2 tables one has the Items (Name UPC etc.) the other is the store info like Store Name etc.

for each Store i need itemName,and storeName both tables or not joint.

Comment: Um. What? Examples of both tables and the required output would help.

Comment: It would be nice to know why you don't want to use a join.

Comment: If you don't want to join the two tables but want to split items from one table by store, you should "Group by StoreId" or similar. It will be up to you to then know which store each storeid belongs to. Or you can expand your question with more information.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by `both tables or not joint.` but you will need to join the two tables.  Something like this for Example:

```
SELECT s.Name, i.Name
FROM Item i
INNER JOIN Store s
ON i.StoreId = s.Id
```

**UPDATE:**

If you just want to select every record in the Items table for every Record in the Store table you could do this:

```
SELECT StoreName, ItemName 
FROM Store, Item
```

If this is what you need then you might want to take a second look at how your DB is structured.

Comment: in the Store table we don't have a ID which is join to the item table

Comment: If there is no connection between Items and Stores then you cannot select the data you want because a relationship does not exist.  Is there another table that defines the relationship?  A `StoreItems` table or something

Comment: Abe thanks, but what can I do in the store table we have 3 rows and I need a list for each item 3 times with each item should be the store name

Comment: Take a look at my update.  I suspect this might be what you are looking for.